# TextView solid shadow

Tags: android, textview

The shadow is created with the following method:

```
textView.getPaint().setMaskFilter(new BlurMaskFilter(5, Blur.OUTER));
```

I found it giving better results than `android:shadow...`, however with a solid black color the *"shadow"* is still too much fuzzy.

Is there any way to make it sharper with relatively large radius ?

Note, documentation mentions I should not modify this `TextPaint`, however I need exactly an outer shadow with a transparent text. If that might be achieved without direct modification of the `TextPaint`, the hint will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

```
@Override
protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
    super.onDraw(canvas);
    super.onDraw(canvas);
}
```